# Disabled 2FA within GithubDesktop

Tags: github, google-authentication

I have a github account setting up with 2FA. Actually I lost my phone, with the Google Authenticator app with it. My recovery code for my github account doens't work, maybe the versions of the code that I have are not the corrects ones, whatever, it doens't work.

So I can't login anymore on Github on Web, however, I'm still connected inside Github Desktop, the app. **Is there a way on github desktop, to disabled 2FA or set an SSH key**, because I saw that with this command, we could manage to get verification code : `ssh -T git@github.com -verify`

Comment: You usually need a 2FA code to disable 2FA. Have you set up your phone number in GitHub? If so, you should be able to get a 2FA code via SMS.

Comment: I didnt find anywhere something to do "retrieve code by sms" :/ So I guess not

Comment: I suggest you read this page from top to bottom: https://help.github.com/en/articles/recovering-your-account-if-you-lose-your-2fa-credentials. Hopefully there's something there that will help you recover your account.

Comment: Already read it, nothing about Github Desktop that could potentially helped me

Comment: I don't think GitHub Desktop is relevant. You won't be able to disable 2FA without providing a 2FA code, regardless of how it happens. (Otherwise the security that 2FA provides would be entirely compromised.) If you've connected one of the partner services you can try recovering your account that way. You should probably contact GitHub support either way. If you can prove you own the account to their satisfaction they may be able to help you recover it.

Comment: Just to add to @Chris', the support link is: https://github.com/contact